# Authenticate with nodejs ldapauth without administrator login?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, ldap

I am trying to use ldapauth to authenticate users in a express web application. The [example](https://github.com/trentm/node-ldapauth#expressconnect-basicauth-example) requires that I supply administrator credentials to start authenticating users and I do not have them (and I do not want to have them, in theory they shouldn't be necessary!).

If I leave those options empty I get an assertion error...

Any ideas to solve it or alternative libraries (ideally available in the npm repository) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than not supplying the `adminDn` and `adminPassword` at all, passing empty strings did trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be not valid anymore as it's validating the config parameters and providing empty strings results in

assert.js:92
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "" == true
    at new LdapAuth (node_modules/ldapauth/lib/ldapauth.js:56:10)

or

LDAP auth error: UnwillingToPerformError: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed

So it seems like a technical user to access the LDAP is needed.